# How to make a StaticLayout text show up on canvas?

Tags: java, android, layout, text, static

I am creating a Live Wallpaper for android 2.3.3 and I want to create a backgroud with text.

Sounds so simple but I don't know how to get the text appear right. It is somewhere out of screen in the top, because when I set a higher text size some of it appears on the top of my screen. Here is my code:

```
void drawWall(Canvas c)
{
c.save();

c.drawColor(0xff000000);

Bitmap _stein = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.stein);

c.drawBitmap(_stein, 0, 0, null);


TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
tp.setColor(Color.WHITE);
tp.setStyle(Style.FILL);
tp.setTextSize(20);


String message = "Some string here";

StaticLayout myStaticLayout = new StaticLayout(message, tp, c.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
c.translate(4*mDensity, 4*mDensity); //same thing with or without this

myStaticLayout.draw(c);

c.restore();
}
```

If you need any more info tell me.